# Nested document.evalute searches?

Tags: javascript, firefox, xpath

```
var links = document.evaluate("//BODY/CENTER[1]/P[1]/TABLE[1]/TBODY[1]/TR[1]", document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,null).evaluate("//A");
```

basically I need to find an element via xpath. then search this element via xpath. The above doesn't work obviously but neither does using contextNode argument.

```
var headings = document.evaluate("//BODY/CENTER[1]/P[1]/TABLE[1]/TBODY[1]/TR[1]", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null); 
var thisHeading = headings.iterateNext();  

var headings2 = document.evaluate("//A", thisHeading, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null); 

headings2.iterateNext().style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

I need to be able to search for children of an element via xpath.

Comment: Why? Can't you simply have a single XPath expression like this: `//BODY/CENTER[1]/P[1]/TABLE[1]/TBODY[1]/TR[1]//A`

Comment: some TR rows do not have A. So I start with the parent element and search for A inside it.

Comment: The fact that "some TR rows do not have A" doesn't prevent using the XPath expression `//BODY/CENTER[1]/P[1]/TABLE[1]/TBODY[1]/TR[1]//A` to select **exactly** all the nodes you want. Just try it.

Comment: I'm not arguing against it just that I need to search the series of sibling parent elements first and record when child is not found inside the parent elements of interest.

Comment: This also can be done with a single XPath expression: `//BODY/CENTER[1]/P[1]/TABLE[1]/TBODY[1]/TR[1][not(//A)]`

Comment: Certainly it can be done with a single XPath. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Good. For your convenience I added this as a separate answer. And +1 to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE` in conjunction with `singleNodeValue` to get the first element of the XPath expression. Then, use `.//A` to select any `<a>` element, which is a child of the matched node. If you want to match a direct child, use `./A`:

```
var headings = document.evaluate("//BODY/CENTER[1]/P[1]/TABLE[1]/TBODY[1]/TR[1]",
                     document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null); 
var thisHeading = headings.singleNodeValue;    
var headings2 = document.evaluate(".//A", thisHeading, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null); 

headings2.iterateNext().style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that the children of `p` tags have to be inline elements. Tables in paragraphs are not allowed. If you remove the `p` tags you can use your source code, see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scessor/eRv7N/).

Comment: Nicely spotted. Add your useful part ("table cannot nest in p") and my useful part ("use `document.evalueate(".//A", ...)`, and the OPs question is answered.

Comment: I have no control over the document.

Answer (score 1):

> basically I need to find an element via xpath. then search this
>   element via xpath

This can be accomplished with a *single XPath expression*.

**Use**:

```
//BODY/CENTER[1]/P[1]/TABLE[1]/TBODY[1]/TR[1]//A
```

**To select all `//BODY/CENTER[1]/P[1]/TABLE[1]/TBODY[1]/TR[1]` elements that *don't* have an `A` descendant, use**:

```
//BODY/CENTER[1]/P[1]/TABLE[1]/TBODY[1]/TR[1][not(//A)]
```